# Add column gapping in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using a table and here's a HTML snippet for the same:

```css
th {
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>
    <td>Exams</td>
    <td>Science</td>
    <td>Mathematics</td>
    <td>Biology</td>
  </th>
  <tr>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>95</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to increase the distance between two column elements. I have added `margin-right`, but it doesn't reflect in the output. Can someone help?

Comment: You can also simply add an empty column with minimal width between the two columns you wish to increase the spacing. Indeed, not a very elegant solution, but it definitely works. The only problem would be if you wish to show borders of the cells. In such case, the empty column would be visible and hence this solution would not be suitable for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `border-spacing` in the rule for the `table` element to create space between the rows and columns, and `padding` on the cells to create additional space inside the cells (including the background).

Note: Your HTML is invalid: `th` elements are special ("header") cells inside a row (`tr`)  - see changed code below.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px 5px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Exams</th>
    <th>Science</th>
    <th>Mathematics</th>
    <th>Biology</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>95</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>33</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there any way to avoid this border-spacing at nth child?

Comment: No, since `border-spacing` is a property of `table`, not of the single cells or rows. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing

Answer (score 1):

You can use [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing). Unless by "gap" you just mean [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use padding which can give the same effect that you want:

```
padding-right: 20px
```

Comment: Actually padding would seperate only the text part, what I wanted to achieve is spacing between the entire td element (including the background).